# I used Joins same table (self join) with having count. But the results are not as expected. I am using Oracle database

Tags: sql, string, oracle, group-by, having

I tried to run the below query. I want all the data in column rp_num to be in the column rp_num_group. And also i want all the data of the column rp_num which is having count more than one (more than one count in std_id, rp_fam,  rn, rp_id) to be in the column std_id_group. But with my query i get the data which is having count more than 1 in both the columns rp_num_group and std_id_group. Kindly suggest the right way to use the joins to get the correct result.

for example, if my table is like below:

```
std_id      rn      rp_id       rp_fam      rp_num

1234        1234    1           abc         a12
1234        1235    1           abc         a34
1234        1236    1           xyz         a56
1244        1246    2           xyz         234
1244        1245    2           hgf         z65
1254        1456    2           hgf         z78
```

I would expect my result to be:

```
std_id      rp_num_group        std_id_group
1234        a12 a34 a56          a12:abc  a34:abc
1244        234 265 z78          z65:hgf  z78:hgf
```

But my result is like below:

```
std_id      rp_num_group        std_id_group
1234        a12 a34            a12:abc  a34:abc
1244        z65 z78            z65:hgf  z78:hgf
```

```
     SELECT DISTINCT rrpn.std_id,  
                          Stringagg(rrpn.rp_num) 
                          over ( 
                            PARTITION BY tmta.rp_id,tmta.rn,tmta.std_id
                            ORDER BY Nlssort(tmta.mta, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI') ROWS 
                          BETWEEN unbounded 
                          preceding AND unbounded following ) AS rp_num_group,
                            Stringagg_distinct(rrpn3.rp_num||':'||rrpn3.rp_fam ) 
                          over ( 
                            PARTITION BY rrpn3.std_id, rrpn3.rn, rrpn3.rp_id 
                            ORDER BY Nlssort(rrpn3.rp_num, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI') ROWS 
                          BETWEEN unbounded 
                          preceding AND unbounded following ) AS std_id_group
        FROM   data_rrpn rrpn 
                join data_rrpn rrpn3
                  ON rrpn3.std_id = rrpn.std_id 
                AND rrpn3.rp_fam = rrpn.rp_fam 
                AND rrpn3.rn = rrpn.rn 
                AND rrpn3.rp_id = rrpn.rp_id 
               join (SELECT std_id, 
                            rp_fam, 
                            rn, 
                            rp_id, 
                            Count(*) 
                     FROM   data_rrpn 
                     GROUP  BY std_id, 
                               rp_fam, 
                               rn, 
                               rp_id 
                     HAVING Count(*) > 1) rrpn2 
                 ON rrpn3.std_id = rrpn2.std_id 
                    AND rrpn3.rp_fam = rrpn2.rp_fam 
                    AND rrpn3.rn = rrpn2.rn 
                    AND rrpn3.rp_id = rrpn2.rp_id 
        ORDER  BY rrpn.std_id;
```

Comment: Please tag your questio with the database that you are running: oracle, postgresql, mysql...?

Comment: ya i have changed. I am using oracle database.

Comment: Your code won't run in Oracle.  What is `stringagg()`?

Comment: stringagg is not oracle function but it is something that exists in our database

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want simple string aggregation,  with filtering on groups having more than one record:

```
select 
    std_id,
    listagg(rp_num, ' ') within group(order by rp_num) rp_num_group,
    listagg(rp_num || ':' || rp_fam, ' ') within group(order by rp_num) std_id_group
from data_rrpn 
group by std_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesnt. it gives the same result in rp_num_group and st_id_group.

Answer (score 0):

You very probably want to to group only on `std_id, rp_fam, rp_id` and *not on* `RN` (which is unique?).

Here you get a preview which `rp_num`s will be considered (`GRP_CNT > 1`):

```
select a.*,
count(*) over (partition by std_id, rp_fam, rp_id) grp_cnt
from tst a;

    STD_ID         RN      RP_ID RP_FA RP_NU    GRP_CNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ----- ----------
      1234       1234          1 abc   a12            2
      1234       1235          1 abc   a34            2
      1234       1236          1 xyz   a56            1
      1244       1245          2 hgf   z65            1
      1244       1246          2 xyz   234            1
      1254       1456          2 hgf   z78            1
```

The final query would be

```
with grp as
(
select a.*,
count(*) over (partition by std_id, rp_fam, rp_id) grp_cnt
from tst a
)
select STD_ID,
  listagg(RP_NUM, ' ') within group(order by RP_NUM) rp_num_group,
  listagg(case when grp_cnt > 1 then RP_NUM || ':' || RP_FAM end, ' ') within group(order by RP_NUM) std_id_group
from grp
group by STD_ID;
```

giving the result:

```
STD_ID, RP_NUM_GROUP, STD_ID_GROUP
1234    a12 a34 a56   a12:abc a34:abc
1244    234 z65 
1254    z78
```

Not sur ehow you get the `z65:hgf  z78:hgf`in your sample result, but I think if there is some additional *magic logic*, you need only adjust the calculation of the `GRP_CNT` using the analytic function as proposed above.